# How can I properly implement QSortFilterProxyModel.parent() to handle a virtual column?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2, model-view

I have the following working code, which opens a `QFileDialog` with an extra column that shows the file name again (pointless, I know, but it’s a result of simplifying my issue):

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MyProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._parents = {}

    def mapToSource(self, index):
        if index.column() == 4:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).mapToSource(index)

    def columnCount(self, index):
        return 5

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and index.column() == 4:
            return self.index(index.row(), 0, self._parents[index]).data(role)
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).data(index, role)

    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if section == 4 and orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal \
                and role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return 'My Column'
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).headerData(section, orientation, role)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if column == 4:
            index = self.createIndex(row, column)
            self._parents[index] = parent
            return index
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).index(row, column, parent)

    def parent(self, index):
        if index.column() == 4:
            return QtCore.QModelIndex()
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).parent(index)


QtWidgets.QApplication([])
dialog = QtWidgets.QFileDialog()
dialog.setOption(dialog.DontUseNativeDialog, True)
dialog.setProxyModel(MyProxyModel(dialog))
dialog.exec_()
```

As you can see, `parent()` is returning an invalid index for items of column 4, and instead I’m retrieving the actual parent inside `data()`, which isn’t ideal. But if I try the following, it exits with an access violation:

```py
(...)
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole and index.column() == 4:
            # Either return causes access violation.
            return self.index(index.row(), 0, self.parent(index)).data(role)
            return self.index(index.row(), 0, index.parent()).data(role)
            return index.sibling(index.row(), 0).data(role)
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).data(index, role)
(...)
    def parent(self, index):
        if index.column() == 4:
            return self._parents[index]
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).parent(index)
(...)
```

I also tried leveraging `QModelIndex`’s internal pointer, with the same result (access violation):

```py
# No __init__() defined; data() exactly like above.
(...)
    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if column == 4:
            return self.createIndex(row, column, parent)
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).index(row, column, parent)

    def parent(self, index):
        if index.column() == 4:
            return index.internalPointer()
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).parent(index)
(...)
```

Pretty sure I’m missing something, but I can’t figure out what it is…

Comment: Huh, just realised that I’m constantly getting `Can't select indexes from different model or with different parents` messages and it’s not letting me select any file, so I’m **definitely** doing something wrong 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the parent should not be invalid, even for a "virtual" index.

Also, in order to properly interact with the fake column, the following three aspects must be considered:

- the `internalId()` of the parent is required for `createIndex()`, otherwise you'll have the same index for the same pair of row/column even if they have different parents;
- `flags()` must return valid flags, in this case you can return the flag of the sibling in the first row;
- `sibling()` must be return the result of `self.index()` for the virtual column, or use a *valid* starting index to compute the sibling;
- `mapToSource` should return a valid *source* index so that the view can properly access its data; an invalid index is usually considered the *root* of the model, and returning it represents an issue: if you double click an index, the file dialog tries to open it, and since an invalid index is considered the root of the file system model (which is a "folder"), it will then navigate to it;

```
class MyProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    # ...
    def mapToSource(self, index):
        if index.column() == 4:
            index = index.sibling(index.row(), 0)
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).mapToSource(index)

    def index(self, row, column, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if column == 4:
            index = self.createIndex(row, column, parent.internalId())
            self._parents[index] = parent
            return index
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).index(row, column, parent)

    def parent(self, index):
        if index.column() == 4:
            return self._parents[index]
        return super(MyProxyModel, self).parent(index)

    def flags(self, index):
        if index.column() == 4:
            return self.flags(index.sibling(index.row(), 0))
        return super().flags(index)

    def sibling(self, row, column, idx):
        if column == 4:
            return self.index(row, column, idx.parent())
        elif idx.column() == 4:
            idx = self.index(idx.row(), 0, idx.parent())
        return super().sibling(row, column, idx)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The only thing that doesn’t work as expected now is double-clicking (or click+Enter) on an item’s virtual column, as it always goes to _(My) Computer,_ but I appreciate this isn’t the original question, and I still have to explore how to handle entering items.

Comment: While the fact that `createIndex()` needs a unique ID makes a lot of sense, I don’t understand why passing it the parent’s `internalId()` wouldn’t result in conflict, as an index with that ID already exists. How does this work?

Comment: @Unai See the update for the selection problem (I forgot about the selection issue). About your other question, the internalId is not a unique id for each index, but it's more of a reference in an abstract coordinate system. You can consider it as the `z` value of a 3d system, where the row is the `x` and the column the `y`: you can have the same `z` for different `x` and `y` values, it doesn't mean that they represent the same point. If you want a more accurate version, you can use the internal id of a sibling: `index = self.createIndex(row, column, self.index(row, 0, parent).internalId())`

Comment: Note: I don't know how *exactly* index ids/pointers are used internally. After some thinking and testing, I believe that, indeed, using the id of an existing sibling index *could* be more appropriate, even if the above code does work fine; that's because, even if the id reference is not "correct", it still ensures that the combination of row/column/id is unique for each index of the fourth column.

Comment: Fascinating, thanks a bunch again! The coordinate analogy makes so much sense, but I still don’t quite understand why we can safely assume that, for any call to `self.index(row, column, parent)`, `row != parent.row() or column != parent.column()`. The sibling approach definitely seems more logical to me, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Is it because parents in a filesystem model are always at the 0th column?

Comment: Precisely: while any index can technically have children, the parent of a tree model is almost always in the first column, and in a file system model it wouldn't make a lot of sense to have children in other columns: file system are actually bidimensional, the other columns in a view are only used for display purposes. QTreeView always makes this "first column as parent" assumption, and that's also the reason for which you can't arrange column headers by moving the first column (the feature has been added in Qt5.11, but the structure is always shown on the first logical column index anyway).

Comment: Unrelated note: while creating an instance of the Qt application without any reference works fine in PySide, it's better practice to create at least a local reference for the it (`app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])`), even if you're not actually using its event loop (`app.exec_()`). Unlike PySide, that's for PyQt mandatory because a Q*Application is a context manager that gets destroyed if not referenced; failing to do so will make the program hang as soon as a new instance of a Qt object or static function requiring an existing QApplication is created/called (any widget, or even a QPixmap).